# How to secure HP Wireless printer?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security, printer

So I while back I purchased and setup an HP Deskjet 3512 wireless printer/scanner.

Got it setup no problems, and been connecting/printing wirelessly just fine.

However, I was scanning wi-fi networks recently, I saw my HP printer displayed as "open" ... O.o   My router is setup ok, and secured, so I'm wondering ... do I have things setup "properly" and securely? or is my printer "exposed" ?

How do I check? 
How do I secure it (if needed)?

[image: Visible wifi networks]
[image: Details of visible wifi printer]

(W-Ditto is my main router. Ditto_Guest is a guest login I will share with other visitors who need wifi access :) )
The other 2 are just neighbours :)

[edit]
adding additional info as I think about it:

a) the printer has an IP via MAC address, assigned by my secure router.

b) however, using this IP I am unable to connect to the "webpage setup" interface (or whatever it's called) .. just never comes back with anything ... no response.

c) IN the printer menu itself, wireless printing is ON, wireless direct is ON.

[/edit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature called Wireless Direct. You can turn it off or password protect it. See page 33 of your [User Guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03471705).

From the printer control panel Home screen touch Wireless and the select Settings.

Comment: Thank you .. I turned Wireless Direct off ... then tried to print a test page, worked fine. So it's setup via my router properly :)  Not sure when/how the wireless direct got turned on, but I didn't know it made it visible ;)  Thanks!!

Comment: Lol. Yeah HP is pretty stupid. This happens all the time. You'd think they had an iota how to keep people secure. I help people secure their HP printers all the time by connecting remotely and printing 500 pages of instructions.